# Problems installing hyper-v feature on windows 10 pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, docker, hyper-v

## Summary

I am trying to setup docker to setup docker I need to enable hyper-v. I tried to enable hyper v but during the reboot, windows say's "we couldn't complete the features undoing changes"

## What I've tried

```batch-file
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
disable firewall
sc config trustedinstaller start=auto
sfc /scannow
```

## Logs

- [cbs.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ezgeRYQ5r905PExdsQpH_V5Ge_rdGsoA/view?usp=sharing)
- [setup log (event viewer)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MRJfFUbVpHacbNESQG4RBXGA87TeNZQa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check your BIOS Setup to ensure Hardware Virtualization and VT-x have been enabled. Enable these, restart and test Hyper-V again.

Comment: It is enabled i have successfully installed hyper v before.

Comment: That is strange. Try the two basic Windows 10 repairs. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run first: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth .  Then run SFC /SCANNOW . Allow both to complete, restart and test.

Comment: Tried that it didn't work.

Comment: Then you now need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the second link , work through it and start with Keep Everything. See if Hyper-V works after.  First make sure Virtual Box and VMware Workstation are not installed.

Comment: wheres the link?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John thank you docker works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Summary:  I am trying to setup docker to setup docker I need to enable
> hyper-v. DISM and SFC did not work.

First make sure Virtual Box and VMware Workstation are not installed.

Assuming not, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the second link , work through it and start with Keep Everything. See if Hyper-V works after that.

Repair Install link (Microsoft Media Creation Link):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.